# Populating ComboBox Value with Object - Object is populated using XML Data

Tags: c#, winforms, xml-serialization, web-to-winforms

This might sound easy for you but I am really struggling with this. I am working on WinForm application with C#(First time). We have a client table in asp.net application.
We are pulling data through WCF. I am able to pull data using WCF and place that in object array.

WCF is passing the data in XML format. I confirmed using SOAP Sonar that the value is getting populated.

This object array has all the values from clients table. I just need to Full Name and Client ID from it. However, I have no clue how can I do that. I tried XML Serialization to deserialize XML. After that I need to populate those values in a combobox, I am quite certain I can do that.

Adding some code for more information:
Function Calling WCF:
'

```
Client[] PopulateClient(string param1){
  Client[] clientlist;
  var ClientListResponse = GetClientList<ClienListResponse>(returninXMLFormat);
  clientlist = ClientListResponse.Items;
  return clientlist;
}

//Another Class calling above function
Client[] getclient(string param)
{
   Client[] callclient(param)
   return callclient;
}
```

'
Now I need to use callclient to populate my combobox.
call client has table with multiple clients and 20 columns. I just need full name and ID.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am using .net Framework 4.0.
Thanks

Comment: There are 2 ways to populate combobox from a collection. First, using `ComboBox.Items` and its `Add method`. Second, using `ComboBox.DataSource`, `ComboBox.DisplayMember` and `ComboBox.ValueMember` to bind the data (collection) to your combobox (`ComboBox.Items` will become read-only in that case).

Comment: @ King. Thanks for the quick response. I understand that part. However, my main concern is how can I populate either properties from that object array I have or how can I get to extract Full name and ID from that Object.

Comment: I don't think you understand it. The standard comboBox can display only 1 field/property, if you want to display more than 1 field/property, you may have to find another control or a custom combobox.

Comment: I mean. I need ID to be used as Value property and Full name as Text property. That Object array is a customized List. Its populated in XML form with table data.

Comment: Please edit your code to make it correct

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir. Your Answer gave me right direction. I am sure, I can solve it now. Thank you for very much. I was on this for last 4 hours. Probably because of Fatigue or maybe just frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have already had your collection/array, here is the detail for what I commented as suggestion:

```
public class Item {
   public string FullName {get;set;}
   public string ID {get;set;}
}
//your array of Item
Item[] items = ...
//Bind your array to your combobox
comboBox.DataSource = items;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "FullName";
comboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
```